# Linking two or more silverlight projects

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, dashboard

I have written two separate silverlight projects that i need to be able to link together. The first project cycles through nine different bar graphs and the second project cycles through three different line charts.

My goal is to have the program first cycle through the first nine bar graphs, after the ninth bar graph start displaying and cycling through the three different line charts, back to the bar graphs, and repeat.

Is there a way that i can link these projects together in this way?

Comment: Why would you want them to be in two separate projects?  Is there any reason they can't be in the same project?

Comment: I wanted them to be separate projects just so i can learn how to link separate projects together...and I wrote them separately without knowing that they were supposed to be linked together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the nature of silverlight, it is NOT advisable to do so. You would want to rewrite them together. Since Silverlight has a XAP file that needs to be written to and compiled and then run inside of the silverlight plugin, it is in your best interest to have a single project. If you want practice learning to "link" separate projects, try a n-tier architecture approach and refactor your service layer into a separate project. Make no mistake, it's definitely possible but that doesn't mean it's the best choice unless you have a very good reason.

If you do want to investigate this further, see the following links.

[Multiple Silverlight Projects in one web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083434/multiple-silverlight-projects-in-one-web-app)

[How To Host More Than One Silverlight User Controls In ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178775/how-to-host-more-than-one-silverlight-user-controls-in-asp-net-web-application)

[Multiple Silverlight Pages with one APX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480343/multiple-silverlight-pages-with-one-apx)

Comment: Could i simply add another silverlight window for the "second" project and just copy paste my xaml/c# code from my actual second project ? Of course i would have to edit some things but i knew that

Comment: When you say another Silverlight window do you mean another view or a new plugin container in the browser, requiring an additional zap file?

Comment: Sorry my terminology sucks. I meant another silverlight user control

Comment: @rage Oh, no problem.  Yes, that is easy then.  Just add the silverlight control directly to the second project.  You don't need two projects for that.  Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: Yes this makes more sense and should be really easy to do. I was able to make a sample program that navigates from one user control to another via button click and it worked fine. I'm just wondering if everytime i navigate to a new user control does all the code in that control run again?


I guess the main thing i'm concerned with is the fact that i have a thread in each user control that controls the "cycling" of my different charts. If i switch to a new user control do the threads of the previous user control still exist?

Comment: @rage It depends on the pattern that you are utilizing.  In the standard MVVM instance pattern, yes, every time you load a control it should initialize your view model that is bound to the control and run through your constructor, default or explicit.  That said, if you finagle your application to use singletons, then it would already be instantiated in memory if you had accessed it prior in most cases.  A lot of this depends on how you manage your views and view models and when you unbind and dispose them.  There isn't necessarily a straightforward answer for your question unfortunately.

Comment: alrighty i'll just dig into it and make it work. Thanks for your help

Comment: @rage  You're welcome!  Best of luck and I hope it helps.  If it did answer your question, I'd greatly appreciate an accepted answer.  If it didn't, I completely understand.  Hopefully it got you that much closer!